# How to make Groovy read from your ClassLoader rather than file system for classes?

Tags: groovy

Id like to sandbox my embedded Groovy, and i would like to introduce an abstraction to where and what it reads when attempting to resolve classes and resources. Are there any libs that patch Groovy to support what i want ?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't any library or abstraction that does it. I'd go for `Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader = <your classloader>`.

Comment: @benjaminMuschko that kind of sux, because anyone can set the ctx cl and it gets tricky to block such attempts with a SecurityManager.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a CMS where users can write their own controllers in Groovy. I load the users's classes using a custom classloader, and I also set an *InheritableThreadLocal<Boolean>* telling my custom SecurityManager that a controller is running.

When this ThreadLocal is set to true, the SecurityManager will prohibit access to certain members through the *checkMemberAccess()* method, and it only allows access to whitelisted classes and packages in the *checkPermission()* method. That way, even if the user uses another classloader to load classes, I can still prevent access to field members .